# How to connect twilio with dialogflow

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es

I followed the tutorial and in the part of the aggregation of the connection variables, and it gives me a permissions error in the variables

The tutorial URL is:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/dialogflow-cx-long-lasting-sessions

I tried to send a message by SMS so that the chatbot would answer the desired phrase but it did not respond. Instead, if the message goes to twilio, it detected that the error is in the connection and shows the following messages:

Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/chroblan-carehnch-242922/locations/us-central1/agents/c08373c6-16ac-4aca-9129-a4b9319b2848' denied.

Comment: When you enabled the Dialogflow CX API, did you choose "No, I'm not using them" under "Are you planning to use this API with App Engine or Compute Engine?"? And did you set up a Service Account and create a key file?